# Resolving Namespace conflicts between a class and a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, rubygems, conflict

In my Rails 2.3 app, I found that the problem emanates from namespace collisions between an existing ActiveRecord model and a gem I recently added.

Specifically, I was trying to add `jammit` support to the app. One of jammit's dependant gems require's `'platform'`, which introduces a `Platform` **module** into the app's namespace. However, I already have an AR **class** with that name, and renaming it will introduce a lot of additional work and possible bugs.

I was wondering if there's a relatively simple way (using ruby's metamagic or whatnot) to prevent this namespace collision without having to rename my class or alter the actual gem. Thanks.

### EDIT:

Instead of renaming/wrapping the **class** `Platform` throughout my app, and since the **module** `Platform` is only required by one other gem, I resulted to forking both gems, renaming `Platform` to `XPlatform` (both for the original gem and the one that imports it), and rebuilding them both. That seemed to work [sigh].

Answer (score 4):

if the conditions are unavoidable when you cannot change the name

try wrapping your activerecord class in a module

```
module YourModule
 class Platform < Activerecord::Base
 named_scope :your_scope, lambda {#your code here}

 end
end
```

So the only change that you have to do is something like

```
YourModule::Platform.your_scope
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea, though I ended just forking the gems I needed and renaming their conflicting names (see my edit). This will work until other gems require them... Which isn't very likely to happen. Thanks!

Comment: @sa125 That's nice.. but what will you do when the gem will have a new version? Will you always upstream you fork with the origin to keep yourself updated?

Comment: The two particular gems ([platform](https://github.com/mmower/platform), [popen4](https://github.com/pka/popen4)) haven't updated in 2-3 years, and I  probably won't need a new version in the foreseeable future.. By that time, I'm hoping to update to Rails 3.x or beyond, and having sprockets built in :)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the class before any actions, you could just make an alias.

NewPlatform = ActiveRecord::

And just use the alias in the action for that class to avoid namespace conflicts.